# Двойной onClick на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пишу простой Todo List на React

```
const list = this.props.item.map((item, index) => {
        return <li key={index}
                   style={{
                       backgroundColor: item.noted ? 'white' : 'red'
                   }}
                   onClick={this.selectCategory.bind(this, index)}
                >
            {item.value}
            <button>edit</button>
            <input
                type="submit"
                value="Delete"
                onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this, index)}

            />
            <button>add</button>
        </li>;
    });
```

Есть 2 onClick если нажать первый то сработает только он, но если нажать на второй то сработают оба, хотя я хочу что б сработал только второй.
Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stopPropagination` в дочернем элементе:

```
<Parent
    onClick={
        (e) => {
            console.log('Parent');
        }
    }
>
    <Child
        onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log('Child');
        }}
    />
</Parent>
```